# Laravel 5.6 Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have searched and found a similar question that was asked before but it did not solve my problem of composer update and composer dumpautoload did not solve it.

I am creating a CMS based website I have created with a PostsController and a create method.

I return a view and the route is below:

```
  Route::get('/post/create',[
'uses' => 'PostController@create',
'as' =>  'post.create'

]);]
```

this is PostsController@create

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
namespace App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Controllers;


class PostsController extends Controller
 {
  /**
   * Display a listing of the resource.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
   public function index()
     {
       //
      }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public function create()
         {
           return view('admin.posts.create');
             }
```

[image: Error screenshot at browser]

Please don't say this question has been asked before.

Help me! I have checked laracast but the link bellow did not work.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/reflectionexception-class-apphttpcontrollersadminadmincontroller-does-not-exist

Comment: Some punctuation would be nice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
'uses' => 'PostController@create',
```

this is Post.

```
class PostsController extends Controller
```

this is Posts.

These are must same. Its just letter mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong route.
Edit your route to

```
Route::get('/posts/create',[
'uses' => 'PostsController@create',
'as' =>  'posts.create'
]);]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of syntax errors. Follow names with caution.

1. Remove second namespace line `namespace App\Http\Controllers\PostController;// remove this one`
2. Error in class name, should  be `use Illuminate\Http\Controller;// singular`
3. Route has to follow exact class name `'uses' => 'PostsController@create',//plural`